# How to allow the fileuploader to accept multiple files while insertion and allow to accept only single file while editing row in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

My file uploader allows multiple selection when i insert data in data base and that inserted data is displayed in gridview how can i make that file uploader multiple selection false when editing the records in gridview
aspx file upload code-

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fil1" runat="server" multiple="multiple" />
```

.cs code

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
          ImageButton img = sender as ImageButton;
         GridViewRow grv = img.Parent as GridViewRow;
        string[] textboxValues = Request.Form.GetValues("DynamicTextBox"); //Request.Form["txtSpeciality"];
        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        this.Values = serializer.Serialize(textboxValues);
        if (e.CommandName == "mybutton")
        {
            GridViewRow gvr = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer;
            int rowIndex = gvr.RowIndex;
            Label Itemid = (Label)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("lblID");
            ID1 = (Itemid).Text;
            Session["ID"] = ID1;
            EditSubjectItem();
            string Role = string.Empty;
            FileUpload fil1 = grv.FindControl("fil1") as FileUpload;
            fil1.AllowMultiple = false;
        }
        //added

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in row editing event:

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    FileUpload fil1 = GridView1.Rows[e.NewEditIndex].FindControl("fil1") as FileUpload;
    fil1.AllowMultiple = false;
}
```

Or, use in row command event:

```html
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton img = sender as ImageButton;
    GridViewRow grv = img.Parent as GridViewRow;
    if (e.CommandName == "mybutton")
    {
        FileUpload fil1 = grv.FindControl("fil1") as FileUpload;
        fil1.AllowMultiple = false;
    }
}
```

## Edited:

Try this getting from your GridViewRow:

```
FileUpload fil1 = (FileUpload)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("fil1");
```

Comment: you can  find using their id in `FindControl("fil1")`

Comment: add this reference `using System.Web.UI.WebControls;` and try

Comment: edit your post and put all the code that has problem/error. This is the right solution of your current problem that you have asked.

Comment: which is the answer where should i post you code how are you making multiple to false in my code can you help me out as i am new to this

Comment: can you please help me out in this